# List out of the range error in python reading RSS Flux on main programm

Tags: python, rss, discord.py

The goal is to have a command in a discord bot that publish the news of a RSS flux

I've this code that take te latest rss news and print it in terminal :

```
print ('Number of RSS posts :', len(NewsFeed.entries))
entry = NewsFeed.entries[1]

print (entry.published)
print ("******")
news = entry.summary
news = news.replace('<p>', '')
news = news.replace('</p>', '')
news = news.replace('<li>', '')
news = news.replace('</li>', '')
news = news.replace('<ul>', '')
news = news.replace('</ul>', '')
news = news.replace('<a>', '')
news = news.replace('</a>', '')
news = news.replace('<strong>', '')
news = news.replace('</strong>', '')
news = news.replace('<s>', '')
news = news.replace('</s>', '')
news = news.replace('<em>', '')
news = news.replace('</em>', '')
news = news.replace('&amp', '&')
print(news)
```

and it work perfectly alone
But when I put it in the main programm of the bot like this (using a bot command)

```
@bot.command (name="warframenews")
    async def warframenews(ctx):
    print("warframenews")
    NewsFeed=feedparser.parse("http://content.warframe.com/dynamic/rss.xml")
    entry = NewsFeed.entries[1]
    news = entry.summary
    news = news.replace('<p>', '')
    news = news.replace('</p>', '')
    news = news.replace('<li>', '')
    news = news.replace('</li>', '')
    news = news.replace('<ul>', '')
    news = news.replace('</ul>', '')
    news = news.replace('<a>', '')
    news = news.replace('</a>', '')
    news = news.replace('<strong>', '')
    news = news.replace('</strong>', '')
    news = news.replace('<s>', '')
    news = news.replace('</s>', '')
    news = news.replace('<em>', '')
    news = news.replace('</em>', '')
    await ctx.send(news)
```

I have a "list out of the range" error but don't now why
The error append on the line "entry = NewsFeed.entry[1]"
please help

Comment: What should this code do if `NewsFeed.entries` has 0 or 1 entries?

Comment: It change the message read in the list (entry is a list)

Comment: Can you show an example of your RSS entries? Likewise, How many entries does it produces, and in what format is it?

Comment: The problem is solved. The problem was the source of the rss Flux